# POSTing with getURL to _blank with variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

For years now I've been using a chat that has the following code to view profiles while passing a variable that does not show in the URL. If the variable matches the userid in the profile page, it allows that user to edit their profile. If it doesn't match, it simply displays the profile instead.

This has worked flawlessly in Firefox and all other browsers until Google Chrome came around. It still works, even in Chrome, except Chrome is making it open as a popup instead of a new tab. I'd like it to open into a new tab. Here is the code:

```
case 'usrp':
var val = node.firstChild.nodeValue;
if(val != null) {
_root.createEmptyMovieClip('profiler', 90);
_root.profiler.flashchatid = this.connid;
_root.profiler.getURL(val, '_blank', 'POST');
}
break;
```

Comment: You can not change browser settings.

Comment: I know, I was just wondering if there was something that would do the same thing my current code does but only it opens in new tabs in all browsers. The code I use now works fine, except in Chrome... it shows a popup, which my users do not like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a common problem with chrome, some create chrome extensions for it...
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/papnlnnbddhckngcblfljaelgceffobn#

As far as I know you can't alter the default behavior of the browser